# How to use find_peaks for spectrum (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I need to automatically find a specific peak to process hundreds of spectra quickly. I have refocused the search for the function on the area of the spectrum I am interested in, but this always gives a far from satisfying result.
I tried with the different parameters: threshold, distance and prominence which seems to be the most adapted but it doesn't find the peaks.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sig

def N_spectres(path_file): 
    spectres = np.loadtxt(path_file, skiprows=1, usecols=(2,3))
    N_spectre = 0
    i=0
    ref = spectres[0,0]
    while i < len(spectres[:,0]) :
        if spectres[i,0]==ref :
            N_spectre +=1
        i+=1
    return N_spectre

##############################################################################
# Data declaration
##############################################################################

file_name = "F837 FeCl3 Rux3 SiO2 E14 MAP cata_532 nm.txt"
os.chdir("DataRenishaw")
correct = 0

#############################################################

file = np.loadtxt(file_name, usecols=(2,3))
N_spectra = N_spectres(file_name)

Nb_point = int(len(file[:,0])/N_spectra)
debut = Nb_point - 230

axes = plt.gca()


plt.show()


i=0
counter=1
while i < len(file[:,0]):
    peaks, _= sig.find_peaks(file[i+debut:i+Nb_point-correct, 1], prominence = 100)
    plt.plot(peaks, file[i+debut:i+Nb_point-correct, 1][peaks], "xr")
    plt.plot(file[i+debut:i+Nb_point-correct, 0], file[i+debut:i+Nb_point-correct, 1])
    axes.set_xlabel("Nombre d'onde (cm^-1)")
    axes.set_ylabel("Intensité")
    #plt.plot(file[i+debut:i+Nb_point, 0], file[i+debut:i+Nb_point, 1])
    plt.title(file_name+"\n Spectre n° : "+str(counter))
    #plt.axis([70,350,2000,10000])
    i+=Nb_point
    counter+=1
    plt.show()
```

On some spectra, a peak appears, it is the one im interested in.
Here is the result :

[image: RBM spectra]

what could I do to get a better result from the find_peaks function ?